# "NotFoundHttpException" using session and login in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm starting a session for saving the language wanted from user before login, after the user logs in, gets "NotFoundHttpException". So to work those routes again, I have to flush the session then everything works perfect again.
Here is Kernel.php

```
 protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageSwitcher::class,

            
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

here is LanguageSwitcher.php middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('locale'))
        {
            App::setLocale(session('locale'));
        }
        $request->session()->put('locale',Config::get('app.locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and here are my api.php routes, for starting a session , on guest mode and after login

```
Route::get('setlocale/{locale}',function($lang){
    session(['locale' => $lang]);
    return response()->json(['successfully changed']);   
})->middleware('web');

Route::middleware(['guest','cors','web'])->group(function ($lang) {

    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::get('/education',[EducationController::class,'index']);
});
Route::middleware(['auth:api','cors','only_verified','web'])->group(function () {
   Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

first I start a session and change language, and head out to /education, then I login, and I try to enter /education which is in guest mode only, throws error, but If I flush the session that I started earlier it works again.

Comment: Did you change anything in your RouteServiceProvider? And since these are in the api routes are you prefixing the urls you hit with /api/?

Comment: Hi Ben. No , I didn't change anything in RouteServiceProvider. and yes every route is hitting /api/.